# How to add validation methods to MVC 6 web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

In my registration form I need to check that the birthdate makes the user over 18 years old.

If I write my own validation (using jquery.validate, which is what aspnetcore 2.0 web app uses) I can get that to work. I don't see the need to do that when the Validation annotations do most of that already.

Custom validation script

```
var $validator = $form.validate({
            errorClass: "help-block text-right animated fadeInDown",
            errorElement: "div",
            errorPlacement: function (error, e) {
                jQuery(e).parents(".form-group > div").append(error);
            },                
            rules: {

                'validation-dateofbirth': {
                    required: true,
                    date: true,
                    checkBirthdate: true
                },
                'validation-gender': {
                    required: true
                },                    
                'validation-password': {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8
                },
                'validation-confirmpassword': {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#validation-password"
                },
                'validation-terms': {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {                    
                'validation-dateofbirth': {
                    required: "Date of Birth required for registration",
                    date: "Please enter your birthdate.",
                    checkBirthdate: "You must be 18 years old to register with us."
                },
                'validation-gender': {
                    required: "Gender selection is required"
                },                   
                'validation-password': {
                    required: "Password is required",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 8 characters long"
                },
                'validation-confirmpassword': {
                    required: "Password confirmation is required",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 8 characters long"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (e) {
                submitFormAfterValidation($form);                    
            }
        });
        $.validator.addMethod("checkBirthdate", function (value, element) {
            var ageLimit = "18";
            var passed = checkBirthDate(value, ageLimit);
            if (!passed) {
                $.validator.messages.checkBirthdate = "Unfortunately, we can only accept registration if you are over " + ageLimit + " years of age";
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });

        function checkBirthDate(dob, ageToCheck) {
            var momentDateFormat = "MM-DD-YYYY";
            var allowed = false;
            dob = moment(dob, momentDateFormat);
            var registerDate = moment().add((parseInt(ageToCheck) * -1), "years")
                .format(momentDateFormat);

            if (dob.isValid()) {
                allowed = dob.isBefore(registerDate);
                //console.log("Allow: " + registerDate + "DOB: " + dob + "..." + "Value: " + allowed);
            }
            return allowed;
        }
```

It seems to me I could just add the method to the current validator that asp.net is using, but I'm not sure how to attach it to that.

I tried just adding

```
//Helpers
$.validator.addMethod("checkBirthdate", function (value, element) {
    var ageLimit = "18";
    var passed = checkBirthDate(value, ageLimit);
    if (!passed) {
        $.validator.messages.checkBirthdate = "Unfortunately, we can only accept registration if you are over " + ageLimit + " years of age";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
function checkBirthDate(dob, ageToCheck) {
    var momentDateFormat = "MM-DD-YYYY";
    var allowed = false;
    dob = moment(dob, momentDateFormat);
    var registerDate = moment().add((parseInt(ageToCheck) * -1), "years")
        .format(momentDateFormat);

    if (dob.isValid()) {
        allowed = dob.isBefore(registerDate);
        //console.log("Allow: " + registerDate + "DOB: " + dob + "..." + "Value: " + allowed);
    }
    return allowed;
}
```

in the page script but that isn't validating the element.

In the custom code I don't have to pass the element, do I need to pass the dob element to the method above for this to work?

I would much prefer to just attach it to the validator  object created with this

```
 @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
```

Is this the best way or should I just create a custom validation annotation to check the birthdate?

Comment: You can write your own `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable` - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke..I know that, I said so in the post. It just seems like for this one validation it would be easier to just attach a method to the jquery validator thats already doing 90% of the work.

Comment: No you cannot do that - if you using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` for MVC's client side validation based on `ValidationAttribute`'s applied to your model, that plugin already initaializes the configures the `$.validator`

Comment: This is a relatively easy `ValidationAttribute` to implement (and you will get both client and more importantly server side validation with less code than is in your question) and I'm sure I've seen an example of it on SO - I'll see if I can find the link to it later today

Comment: Could not find that SO post, but [Unobtrusive Client and Server Side Age Validation in MVC using Custom Data Annotations](http://www.macaalay.com/2014/02/24/unobtrusive-client-and-server-side-age-validation-in-mvc-using-custom-data-annotations/) is a complete example (modify it to remove the max age if you want)

Comment: Ok, will go that route. Thanks